# Sorting through filenames containing letters and numerals in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sorting

I am trying to import some csv files in a sorted manner. Here are a few filenames.

`market_rate_352_1.csv, market_rate_352_5.csv, market_rate_352_10.csv, market_rate_352_25.csv, market_rate_352_100.csv, market_rate_352_200.csv`

Now while importing I use `sorted(glob.glob('market_rate_*.csv'))`. But it sorts the file in this way,

`market_rate_352_100.csv, market_rate_352_10.csv, market_rate_352_1.csv, market_rate_352_200.csv, market_rate_352_25.csv, market_rate_352_5.csv`

But I want it as:

`market_rate_352_1.csv, market_rate_352_5.csv, market_rate_352_10.csv, market_rate_352_25.csv, market_rate_352_100.csv, market_rate_352_200.csv`

I tried splitting the names and then sorting using `files.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.strip('market_rate_')))`, where files is the array of filenames. But it throws an error, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'`. I guess this is because my file still contains an underscore and `.csv` string. I am not sure how to split twice and then sort through the files. Or if there is a much easier way to do it.

Comment: You might want to check out [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/).

Comment: Thanks, mate. This is perfect. If you want to add it as an answer, I will accept it. @mportes

Answer (score 1):

Your sort is doing an alphabetic sort but you want it to be (partly) numeric.

The easiest way to write the `key=` function is to write it as a named function rather than to cram it as a one-liner into a lambda.

```
def split_numeric(s):
    # Take the stem of the filename, no extension, and split on underscores
    elements = s.partition(".")[0].split("_")
    # Convert the numeric elements into integers for numeric sorting
    return [int(e) if e.isdigit() else e for e in elements]

filenames = ['market_rate_352_10.csv', 'market_rate_352_5.csv', 'market_rate_352_1.csv']

filenames.sort(key=split_numeric)
```

Result:

```
['market_rate_352_1.csv', 'market_rate_352_5.csv', 'market_rate_352_10.csv']
```